# How to setup a success_hook to with send messages from telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, dagster

I'm new one in Dagster. Could you help me, please? I want to understand how to set up an etl process error notification through a telegram bot

My code:

```
import pygsheets
import os
import telegram
from dagster import resource
from typing import Callable, Optional
from dagster._core.definitions import success_hook
from dagster._core.execution.context.hook import HookContext
```

**create a resource:**

```
@resource
def send_message(message):
    botid = os.environ['telegram_bot']
    chat = os.environ['telegram_chat']
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=botid)   
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat, text=message, parse_mode='HTML')
```

**create ops:**

```
@op (required_resource_keys={"telegram"})
def load_df(merged_df):
    # путь до credentials
    PATH = os.getenv(PATH_TO_FILE)
    gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file=PATH)
    gc = gc.open_by_key(os.getenv('OPEN_BY_KEY'))
    sheet = gc.worksheet('title', 'Список для ОЦЕНКИ NEW')
    sheet.set_dataframe(merged_df, start=(1,1))

@op(required_resource_keys={'telegram'})
        def telegram_op(context):
            context.resources.telegram.send_message(text=':wave: hey there!')
```

**create a job:**

```
@job (resource_defs={"telegram": send_message}, hooks={telegram_on_success}, op_retry_policy = default_policy)
def job_text_for_pictures():
    load_df(merged_df)
```

**create a hook:**

```
def _default_status_message(context: HookContext, status: str) -> str:
    return "Op {op_name} on job {pipeline_name} {status}!\nRun ID: {run_id}".format(
        op_name=context.op.name,
        pipeline_name=context.pipeline_name,
        run_id=context.run_id,
        status=status,
    )

def _default_success_message(context: HookContext) -> str:
    return _default_status_message(context, status="succeeded")

def telegram_on_success(
    message_fn: Callable[[HookContext], str] = _default_success_message,
    dagit_base_url: Optional[str] = "http://localhost:3000",
):

    @success_hook(required_resource_keys={"telegram"})
    def _hook(context: HookContext):
        text = message_fn(context)
        if dagit_base_url:
            text += "\n<{base_url}/instance/runs/{run_id}|View in Dagit>".format(
                base_url=dagit_base_url, run_id=context.run_id
            )
        context.resources.telegram.send_message(text=text)  # type: ignore
    return _hook
```

**And after that I get an error:** dagster._core.errors.DagsterSubprocessError: During multiprocess execution errors occurred in child processes:
In process 2984: dagster._core.errors.DagsterResourceFunctionError: Error executing resource_fn on ResourceDefinition telegram

Comment: what problem are you running into? can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: @zyd Hello! I added my question

Comment: the error makes it seem that when it's trying to initialize your `telegram` resource it's running into an error. You didn't provide your code for the telegram resource so it's kinda tough to say what the problem might be, but I'd start looking there.

Comment: @zyd for telegram i declare a function def send_message as resoursce

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are not yet implemented with the "software defined assets" you are using. You can upvote for the feature here : https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/issues/8577

You have to imagine a workaround for the moment.